# Do I have to implement key twice for EF code first with inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, data-annotations, subclass

I have an abstract superclass DataContent:

```
public abstract class DataContent
{
    [Key(), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Sheet")] //Foreign Key van Sheet
    public int SheetId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DataContent(int i, string n)
    {
        Id = i;
        Name = n;
    }
```

and 3 subclasses, for example EmptyContent:

```
public class EmptyContent: DataContent
{

    //TODO: Do these keys have to be here as well???
    [Key(), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Sheet")] //Foreign Key van Sheet
    public int SheetId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }


    public EmptyContent (int i, string n) : base(i,n)
    {
        Text = "";

    }

}
```

My question is: Do I have to declare the (foreign) keys twice for the Entity Framework to generate the database? or can I just put them in the superclass Datacontent only?

[Still a student so sorry if this question seems stupid to you :)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each property can be implemented only once (name must be unique in the whole hierarchy). Your derived classes shouldn't have any properties from the base class unless they override them.

Comment: so I can just delete them in the subclass and they will be inherited, and the entity framework will recognize these and make separate tables for each subclass in the database?

Comment: one main purpose of the whole inheritance-concept is that you don´t have to define "shared" properties multiple times. Im pretty sure that EF can deal with that. Just try it.

Comment: You must mark each class with `Table` attribute and specify table name to use TPT inheritance otherwise EF will use TPH inheritance and all entities will be mapped to single table.